# 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

I'm new to Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8.

I have been able to get a simple app to work just fine, but it would throw the same "exceptions".

So to test, I just started a brand new blank JavaScript project, and just linked the jQuery code in default.html, and ran the debugger, and the following exceptions are still thrown :

```
Exception was thrown at line 1217, column 4 in ms-appx://xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 1235, column 4 in ms-appx://xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
```

**How can I edit the jQuery code or what do I need to do to get rid of this exception being thrown?**

The part of the jQuery code where the first exception is being thrown :

```
assert(function (div) {
    // Support: Windows 8 Native Apps
    // The type and name attributes are restricted during .innerHTML assignment
    var input = doc.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    div.appendChild(input).setAttribute("name", "D");

    // Support: IE8
    // Enforce case-sensitivity of name attribute
    if (div.querySelectorAll("[name=d]").length) {
        rbuggyQSA.push("name" + whitespace + "*[*^$|!~]?=");
    }

    // FF 3.5 - :enabled/:disabled and hidden elements (hidden elements are still enabled)
    // IE8 throws error here and will not see later tests
    if (!div.querySelectorAll(":enabled").length) {
        rbuggyQSA.push(":enabled", ":disabled");
    }

    // Opera 10-11 does not throw on post-comma invalid pseudos
    div.querySelectorAll("*,:x"); // *********** THIS IS LINE 1217 ***********
    rbuggyQSA.push(",.*:");
});
```

The part of the jQuery code where the second exception is being thrown :

```
if ( (support.matchesSelector = rnative.test( (matches = docElem.matches ||
    docElem.webkitMatchesSelector ||
    docElem.mozMatchesSelector ||
    docElem.oMatchesSelector ||
    docElem.msMatchesSelector) )) ) {

    assert(function( div ) {
        // Check to see if it's possible to do matchesSelector
        // on a disconnected node (IE 9)
        support.disconnectedMatch = matches.call( div, "div" );

        // This should fail with an exception
        // Gecko does not error, returns false instead
        matches.call( div, "[s!='']:x" ); // ***** THIS IS LINE 1235 *****
        rbuggyMatches.push( "!=", pseudos );
    });
}
```

TooLongDon'tRead - Things I've tried :

From what I understand, it's suppose to throw the exception, however microsoft won't approve an app that is throwing any errors/exceptions... I'm quite confused that there isn't a clear cut answer to this (that is easily found), since it is likely an issue everyone has that uses jquery with visual studio. I even tried using jquery2.02 which people said didn't throw these exceptions , but it still did for me. I tried editing the jquery code myself, but that caused a whole lot of other errors.

I also tried the jquery for windows 8 in nuget (that hasn't been updated in like 2 years)... that I guess was suppose to resolve this stuff, but it actually gave me even more runtime errors.

Comment: Since going by the comments these exceptions are expected, I assume they will be caught internally by jQuery. If those exceptions never reach top-level, are you sure this is a problem for Microsoft? The app uses exceptions internally to propagate errors, but that's not unusual and doesn't mean the app crashes. It would be strange if Microsoft would not allow this.

Comment: @sth - I think you are right.  This issue can occur when Visual Studio is configured to break on all JavaScript errors.  This error is expected, and handled by jQuery, but Visual Studio doesn't know that.  Seems that if I ignore the error and carry on, all is well...

Answer (score 10):

I encountered a similar issue with jQuery when using IE11. It turns out that even though JQuery 2.1.1 claims to be IE11 compatible, I found that in some situations it's not and returns errors. Try using the most recent JQuery 1.X build. it has the exact same functionality as 2.1.1, but still has the compatibility checks for IE 7, 8 and 9 that were removed in 2.1.1.

Comment: per my last comment - never mind.  This issue can occur when Visual Studio is configured to break on all JavaScript errors. This error is expected, and handled by jQuery, but Visual Studio doesn't know that. Seems that if I ignore the error and carry on, all is well...

Comment: @Barry picker How do I stop breaking for Jquery errors in the application

Comment: @ManojNayak - to stop breaking for any specific kind of errors look at the Exceptions Settings in Visual Studio.  This can be seen by opening the Exception Settings window.  See Visual Studio menus item 'Debug', then sub menu 'Windows', then sub menu 'Exception Settings' or by shortcut key Ctrl+Alt+E.  You may want to play with the exception settings called 'JavaScript Runtime Exceptions' to get the results you are after....

Answer (score 4):

If the `window` object is available, define a `window.onerror` function to catch all uncaught exceptions:

```
 window.onerror = function (message, url, lineNo)
  {
  console.log('Error: ' + message + '\n' + 'Line Number: ' + lineNo);

  return true;
  }

console.log(window);
console.log(1=2);
```

**References**

- [Better Error Handling With window.onerror](http://dev.opera.com/articles/better-error-handling-with-window-onerror/)
- [W3C Wiki: window.onerror](http://www.w3.org/wiki/DOM/window.onerror)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when I moved my web page from VS10 to VS12.  I thought the problem was somehow having to do with the transfer.  I read the above questions and answers and concluded that my error was testing using Windows 8.1 and IE 11.  I tested my VS12 version software using the FireFox browser and the error has gone.  I don't know how to change the jQuery in IE 11 to build 1.x.  If I did I would because I want my software to operate using the most popular browsers.

Thank you for all your help.