# jQuery: "0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError" - Why Syntax Error?

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

I just made the mistake in Visual Studio 2013 of Ticking the "Break on this type of error" while debugging my web forms app.

When I tried to run my application again, it kept halting during the startup of the application in the jScript with a syntax error (0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError). I eventually unchecked the debugger box and my application started working again.

Now I expect that a top quality script like jQuery will throw errors when I (or the system) do something wrong, but can anyone explain why it would be throwing Syntax Errors during the normal execution of the script?

REVISED, AMPLIFIED QUESTION:

I understand, and it is clearly documented, that jScript uses handled exceptions to avoid having to check for various situations. This is not a bug in of itself. I extensively use handle exceptions in my code and they are great for unusual error conditions.  However, I try to avoid at all costs any syntactical errors in my code that might arise at runtime.

I also know from extensive googling, and following up on links, that the use of exceptions is considered normal for jScript and however much it interferes with the use of Visual Studio in debugging scripts, that both parties consider it a problem with the other party's product.

However, my question is much simpler. What is it that jScript is doing that validly produces Syntax Errors that because they are handled, are not considered errors?

At this point, I have solved my immediate problem. I have posted this question to try to understand why invalid code is considered "not a bug".  Handled exceptions are "not a bug", but to me "Syntax Errors" are. Why am I wrong?

Comment: jQuery doesn't have *syntax errors*. If it had - it wouldn't run in your app successfully.

Comment: Similiar question that I started.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131986/0x800a139e-javascript-runtime-error-syntaxerror

Comment: Similar question, but not the same. I read your question first, but my question is not why exceptions, but why Syntax Error?

Comment: zerkms: I do not know what the error is, I would not expect jQuery to contain any Syntax Error, but this is what Visual Studio 2013 is reporting. My question is WHY?

Comment: Have you Googled this issue? For example, see this [thread on the ASP.NET forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1919704.aspx?JavaScript+runtime+error+0x800a139e+SyntaxError)

Comment: Also see [ticket #14123 in the jQuery Core Bug Tracker](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14123)

Comment: Boaz - Oh yes! Googled a lot. Spent hours until I found that I had just accidentally ticked the "Break on this type of error" box in VS Debugger. Unchecking that got me going again.

BUT: It got me wondering why we would be getting Syntax Errors in production code. There are plenty of Google questions (both your links are good, but ask the question, not give the solution). In fact the jQuery Core Bug Tracker declares that it is "not a bug" but fails to indicate why.

Comment: @Mythlandia The two sources clearly state why this happening and why you should not consider this a *bug*.

Comment: I suggest the question heading include the word jQuery because that is what this relates to and what others would be searching on. "Why does jQuery throw syntax exceptions (which are handled)".

Answer (score 0):

It seems that jQuery makes assumptions on variables that are not always true and hence gives a Syntax Error when those variables do not exist in the expected form.