# IBM MobileFirst 7.1 + Ionic on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, ionic-framework, windows-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm currently experimenting MobileFirst + Ionic across all platforms(what I'd tested: IOS, Android ,Windows and Web).

The [guide](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2016/01/13/ionic-hybrid-mobile-app-using-mobilefirst-platform-7-1-cli/) that I followed.

Everything was working fine except for Windows Universal platform.

I'd built with Visual Studio 2013 and deployed on Windows 8.1. The app was built without error and runs. Later, I encountered following runtime error when I performed user interaction:

```
'WWAHost.exe' (Script): Loaded 'Script Code (MSAppHost/2.0)'. 
Exception was thrown at line 4350, column 4 in ms-appx://316fdfca-e76a-477c-8ba4-1697624e2ab4/www/default/worklight/wljq.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 4368, column 4 in ms-appx://316fdfca-e76a-477c-8ba4-1697624e2ab4/www/default/worklight/wljq.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 8618, column 36 in ms-appx://316fdfca-e76a-477c-8ba4-1697624e2ab4/www/default/worklight/wljq.js
0x800a01ad - JavaScript runtime error: Automation server can't create object
Exception was thrown at line 147, column 118 in ms-appx://316fdfca-e76a-477c-8ba4-1697624e2ab4/www/default/worklight/worklight.js
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'crypto' is undefined
Exception was thrown at line 15274, column 11 in ms-appx://316fdfca-e76a-477c-8ba4-1697624e2ab4/www/default/3party/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngLocale' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/nomod?p0=ngLocale
```

I also included [winstore-jscompat.js](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/winstore-jscompat) in my project.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to IBM:

---

If you are developing a Windows 8 app with Worklight, you may have noticed two JavaScript exceptions being thrown in Visual Studio's output window:

```
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'crypto' is undefined
```

Analysis of the two errors has shown that they do not result from defects in Worklight. The syntax error in /www/default/worklight/wljq.js is expected and handled by the jQuery library. Visual Studio is not aware that the jQuery library is handling it, so it will still print this error, provided it is configured to break on JavaScript errors. More details on this error can be found in this StackOverflow question:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131986/0x800a139e-javascript-runtime-error-syntaxerror
```

The crypto error in /www/default/worklight/worklight.js results from an open source library that is used by Worklight. Since this error is outside the Worklight code base, we will not be able to provide a fix for it.

While some concern has been raised over these errors, they should not alter the app's functionality and can be safely ignored.

---

Source: [Runtime Exceptions in Windows 8 apps](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/runtime_exceptions_in_windows_8_apps?lang=en)

Comment: I'm aware of the thread you shared. But the weird thing is it only happen in worklight application with ionic or angular. it doesn't happen to me if I created a project without ionic.