# Windows 10 app using angular and cordova

Tags: windows, visual-studio, angular, cordova

I'm trying to create an windows 10 app from an angular project. This is my first time using it.
I'm using visual studio 2017 with cordova tools.
The project generated contains a www folder.

After building my angular project, i removed files inside and moved all my dist contents into that www folder.

Then i tried to build and run my project within visual studio with local machine windows-64.
Everything works fine for now, build success and run as well. 
But it generates a white screen just after the splashscreen

In my output console i have : 
Exception was thrown at line 1, column 25606 in ms-appx-web://.../www/scripts/vendor.71fa8c15.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError
Exception was thrown at line 1, column 26118 in ms-appx-web://.../www/scripts/vendor.71fa8c15.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError

I'm new to this and i would like to know if i'm missing one step or anything else. Is there something different to do with windows 10 application ?

By the way, if i build it with android or ios it works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131986/0x800a139e-javascript-runtime-error-syntaxerror)

Comment: tldr: Just downgrade your version of jquery so that IE is supported

Comment: Should i downgrade my jquery with bower before i build it with angular ? Which jquery version should i use ?

Comment: Yes, I think you need 1.12.4 ... also note the comment on the other answer: This issue can occur when Visual Studio is configured to break on all JavaScript errors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i still have my blank screen. Doesn't seem to work for me.In my angular project if i run a grunt serve it will work with internet explorer.

Comment: I tried to catch all uncatch errors but still didn't work...